# Restrict certain extensions on lightning component file upload

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, fileupload

I have a lightning component for uploading files on salesforce. On the code, I have listed all the acceptable file extensions allowed like this

<aura:attribute name="accept" type="List" default="['.jpg', '.jpeg','.jfif','.pjp','.png','.svg','.tif','.tiff','.gif','.webp']"/>

{!v.fileName}

This is working. When i click the upload button, it wont let me select a pdf file from my computer. But when I type the file name of the pdf, I was able to select and upload successfully..

[image: Selecting a pdf to upload]

Is there a way to avoid this?